# Sort in descending order in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark (Python 2.7.9/Spark 1.3.1) and have a dataframe GroupObject which I need to filter & sort in the descending order. Trying to achieve it via this piece of code.

```
group_by_dataframe.count().filter("`count` >= 10").sort('count', ascending=False)
```

But it throws the following error.

```
sort() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ascending'
```

Comment: unbelievably, this still exists in the spark 3.2.0.

Comment: For some reason, this works for me as is. Using #databricks #spark-3.4.1

Answer (score 228, accepted):

In PySpark 1.3 `sort` method doesn't take ascending parameter. You can use `desc` method instead:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

(group_by_dataframe
    .count()
    .filter("`count` >= 10")
    .sort(col("count").desc()))
```

or `desc` function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

(group_by_dataframe
    .count()
    .filter("`count` >= 10")
    .sort(desc("count"))
```

Both methods can be used with with Spark >= 1.3 (including Spark 2.x).

Answer (score 155):

Use **orderBy**:

```
df.orderBy('column_name', ascending=False)
```

Complete answer:

```
group_by_dataframe.count().filter("`count` >= 10").orderBy('count', ascending=False)
```

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Answer (score 35):

By far the most convenient way is using this:

```
df.orderBy(df.column_name.desc())
```

Doesn't require special imports.

Comment: Credit to [Daniel Haviv](https://www.linkedin.com/in/danielhaviv/) a Solutions Architect at Databricks who showed me this way.

Comment: by far the best answer here.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer instead. Much simpeler and doesnt rely on packages (perhaps wasn't available at the time)

Comment: I really like this answer but didn't work for me with count in spark 3.0.0. I think is because count is a function rather than a number.
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <bound method DataFrame.count of DataFrame[...]> of type <class 'method'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.

Comment: This orderBy (sort) works in Azure Synapse Analytics, when reading from dedicatedp1 using "spark.read.synapsesql"

Answer (score 7):

you can use groupBy and orderBy as follows also

```
dataFrameWay = df.groupBy("firstName").count().withColumnRenamed("count","distinct_name").sort(desc("count"))
```

Comment: Why are you first renaming the column and then using the old name for sorting? Renaming is not even a part of the question asked

Comment: @Sheldore I am renaming the column name for the performance optimization while working with aggregation queries its difficult for Spark to maintain the metadata for the newly added column

Answer (score 6):

In pyspark 2.4.4

```
1) group_by_dataframe.count().filter("`count` >= 10").orderBy('count', ascending=False)

2) from pyspark.sql.functions import desc
   group_by_dataframe.count().filter("`count` >= 10").orderBy('count').sort(desc('count'))
```

No need to import in 1) and 1) is short & easy to read, 
**So I prefer 1) over 2)**

Comment: Why are you using both orderBy and sort in the same answer in 2)?

Answer (score 1):

RDD.**sortBy**(keyfunc, ascending=True, numPartitions=None)

an example:

```
words =  rdd2.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
counter = words.map(lambda word: (word,1)).reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)

print(counter.sortBy(lambda a: a[1],ascending=False).take(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

PySpark added [Pandas style sort operator](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6958) with the `ascending` keyword argument in version 1.4.0. You can now use

```
df.sort('<col_name>', ascending = False)
```

Or you can use the `orderBy` function:

```
df.orderBy('<col_name>').desc()
```

Comment: `df.orderBy('<col_name>').desc()` this gave error the first command worked

Answer (score -2):

You can use [pyspark.sql.functions.desc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.desc.html) instead.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc

g.groupBy('dst').count().sort(desc('count')).show()
```